# Vuetify componente "v-navigation-drawer": bug quando dou scroll na página

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estou com o seguinte problema com o componente v-navigation-drawer do Vuetify: se eu estiver no topo da página, ele funciona corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, caso eu desça um pouco (scroll), o conteúdo do v-navigation-drawer sobe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém que já passou pelo mesmo sabe se tem alguma propriedade para fixar isso, ou terei que fazer na mão?

Código:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="$store.state.showSidebar"
    absolute
    temporary
  >
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-img :src="publicPath + 'assets/img/deyvid.jpg'"></v-img>
      </v-list-item-avatar>

      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ app.author }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item 
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          link
          @click="redirect(item.href)"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        app: this.$store.state.app,
        publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
        items: [
          { title: 'Home', icon: 'mdi-home', href: 'Home' },
          { title: 'About me', icon: 'mdi-information', href: 'About' },
          { title: 'My projects', icon: 'mdi-folder-open', href: 'Projects' },
        ],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      redirect(routerName) {
        this.$router.push({ name: routerName })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Utiliza a propriedade chamada Fixed do componente, e pronto. Resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente trocar o absolute por app

De:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="$store.state.showSidebar"
    absolute
    temporary>
```

Por:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="$store.state.showSidebar"
    app
    temporary
  >
```

Faça o mesmo com o componente v-app-bar